# Eager loading in model associations getter

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is that possible to do Eager loading when getting model associations?

Having three models: Category <= Product <= Image.

I want to get all products with images within requested category.

Such call doesn't work:

```
category.getProducts({include: [Image]})
```

Any alternative?
Or just raw SQL query will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding suport is underway but not yet implemented: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/388